# Unable to get the Javascript sourced data by column filtering using data tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am trying to load js sourced data into the table via data table.js

the loading works fine, however when I introduce the column filtering, the feature fails. I need to have  Javascript sourced data with column filtering using data tables

More about column filtering: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html

More about js source data: 
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
<style>
thead input {
        width: 100%;
}    
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">  
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">  
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
</table>
    
    
<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {
       
var dataSet = [
    [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
    [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
    [ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ],
    [ "Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060" ],
    [ "Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700" ],
    [ "Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000" ],
    [ "Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000" ],
    [ "Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600" ],
];


        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( '#example thead' );
            $('#example thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i) {
                var title = $(this).text();
                $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
         
                $( 'input', this ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                    if ( table.column(i).search() !== this.value ) {
                        table
                            .column(i)
                            .search( this.value )
                            .draw();
                    }
                } );
            } );
         
            var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
                orderCellsTop: true,
                data: dataSet,
                fixedHeader: true,
                columns: [ { title: "Name" },
                          { title: "Position" },
                          { title: "Office" },
                          { title: "Extn." },
                          { title: "Start date" },
                          { title: "Salary" }
                        ],
            } );
        } );
});
</script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you declare the columns when initializing the datatable, the table-head is not present at the moment you try to modify it. You need to clone the table-head elements and do the modifications after the datatables-object is completely initialized.

You can use the `initComplete`-property of the datatables-settings:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  let dataSet = [
    ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"],
    ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750"],
    ["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000"],
    ["Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060"],
    ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"],
    ["Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000"],
    ["Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000"],
    ["Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600"],
  ];

  let table = $('#example').DataTable({
    orderCellsTop: true,
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [{ title: "Name" }, { title: "Position" }, { title: "Office" }, { title: "Extn." }, { title: "Start date" }, { title: "Salary" }],
    initComplete: function(settings, json) {
      $('#example thead tr').clone(false).appendTo('#example thead');
      $('#example thead tr:eq(1) th').each(function(i) {
        let title = $(this).text();
        $(this).removeClass('sorting sorting_asc sorting_desc');
        $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
        $('input', this).on('keyup change', function() {
          if (table.column(i).search() !== this.value) {
            table.column(i).search(this.value).draw();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
  
});
```

```css
thead input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%"></table>
```